# MVC4 Send Datatable to View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, datagrid, model, datatable, sqldatareader

I need to pass a list of TestModel into my view.  This list will then be used to populate a grid.  However, I want the members of TestModel to be created dynamically from headers in a datatable loaded from sqldatareader.

Is this possible?  If so, how?  If not, are there any other alternatives for loading a grid in my view with the columns and rows from my datatable?

If I strongly type my view using this:

```
@using System.Data;
@model System.Data.DataTable
```

Then I get down to mapping the datatable to the grid

```
@{
    var grid = new WebGrid(Model, defaultSort: "Name");
}
```

I get these errors:

```
The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.Helpers.WebGrid.WebGrid(System.Web.HttpContextBase, string, int, bool, bool, string, string, string, string, string, string, string)' has some invalid arguments
```

and

```
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Data.DataTable' to 'System.Web.HttpContextBase'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I had not edited my controller to pass a datatable, it was still trying to pass a model of type "TestModel."

Comment: could you demonstrate the code you used in the Controller to pass the datatable? I've just run into the issue myself, and I'm still learning the complexities of the WebGrid. Thanks.